# Problem with understanding Time Evolution of a Quantum State

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hamiltonian, time-evolution, quantum-states

I was given the following task and I'm having some troubles with understanding a few things about it:

> There is given a system with Orthonormal basis $ |u_1 \rangle , |u_2 \rangle, |u_3 \rangle$  and two operators: Hamiltonian $H$ and some operator $A$ given by:
>
> \begin{align} 
> H|u_1\rangle & = 2E_0|u_1\rangle − E_0|u_3\rangle, \\
> H|u_2\rangle & = E_0|u_2\rangle,  \\
> H|u_3\rangle & = −E_0|u_1\rangle − 2E_0|u_3\rangle,  \\
> A & = a \left(\text{ }  4|u_1\rangle\langle u_1| + 2|u_2\rangle\langle u_2| - 2|u_3\rangle\langle u_3| \right )
> \end{align}
>
> In the moment $t_0$ there was a measurement of energy, that gave the highest possible value; in the moment $t_1$ there was a measurement of $A$, that gave the lowest possible value.
>
> 1. Give the evolution of state from $t_0$ to $t_1$
> 2. Give the state just after the measurement of A and the evolution of this state for $t > t_1$.

Now, as far as I understand correctly, the state in the moment $t_0$ had a form of the highest eigenvalue of energy and the eigenstate corresponding to that energy, e.g. $E_1 |1 \rangle $, and thus the time evolution of this state should look like this I guess: $\exp \left(-iE_1 \left( \frac{t-t_0}{ħ} \right) \right) |1 \rangle .  $

If my reasoning is correct then I don't know what the measurement of $A$ actually tells us and what will be the state and the evolution of this this state after the measurement in $t_1$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you determined the explicit form of the states alluded to in your basis, as implicitly required to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you understand how the initial measurement of $H$ and time evolution from $t_0$ to $t_1$ works.  Without giving away the details, the same reasoning applies to measurement of $A$: after measurement of $A$, given that the measurement returns the lowest eigenvalue of $A$, the state should be the corresponding eigenstate of $A$.  The challenge will be finding this state and expressing it in *an appropriate basis* in order to find the time evolution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I still have some doubts: firstly, you state that after the measurement of A the state of the system will be given by eigenstate of A and not H (if I understand correctly). I thought that the whole system state should be given by eigenstates of energy (so eigenstates of H), but I am not certain about this, so correct me if I'm wrong. Secondly, by "appropriate basis", do you mean I have to express the state after measurement of A in basis of Hamiltonian eigenstates? I think this was suggested to me by my teacher, although once again - I'm not sure.

Comment: Since this appears to be a homework question, I'm trying not to give too much away.  You are right that any state can be expressed as a superposition of energy eigenstates, but in general the system state need not be in a *particular* energy eigenstate.  With regard to the choice of basis, I approve of your teacher's suggestion ;)  You know how the energy eigenstates evolve in time, so writing your state of interest in terms of these will tell you how *it* evolves in time.

Comment: I think this answers all my questions and I should be able to solve it now. Your insight on this have been a great help for me, so thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad it was helpful!